# Close a Form or multiple Forms opened in a UserControl

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, user-controls

I have a main Form (`Form1`) with an UserControl (`ucModule2`).
`ucModule2` contains a button (`simpleButton1`) which opens another Form (`Form2`).
On `Form1`, I have a button (`UsrCtrlDialog`) which should close `Form2`.

I have two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**
My `ucModule2.cs`:

```
public partial class ucModule2 : UserControl
{
    public static Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
        fr2.Show();
        fr2.TopMost = true;
        textModule2 = textBox_ucModule2.Text;
    }
 }
```

`Form1`'s button used to close `Form2`:

```
private void UsrCtrlDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form2 fr2 = new Form2();            
    ucModule2.fr2.TopMost = false;
    ucModule2.fr2.Close();
    ucModule2.fr2.Dispose();
}
```

In this scenario, `Form2` is opened only once and is closed when the `UsrCtrlDialog` button, from `Form1`, is closed. But if I want to open again `Form2`, I get, on `fr2.Show()`:

> `System.ObjectDisposedException` exception ('Cannot access a disposed
>   object.'`

I know that when I want to open again `Form2`, a new object of `Form2` type isn't created.
What can I do to be able to open a new Form2 after the old one was closed?

**Scenario 2:**
My `ucModule2.cs`:

```
public partial class ucModule2 : UserControl
{
    //public static Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
        fr2.Show();
        fr2.TopMost = true;
        textModule2 = textBox_ucModule2.Text;
    }
}
```

In this scenario, I can open as many `Form2` windows as I click on `simpleButton1`. For example, I press 3 times `simpleButton1`. I will have 3 `Form2` windows.

How could close the 3 `Form2` windows when I press `UsrCtrlDialog` button form `Form1`? How could I get the `fr2` object from `ucModule2.cs` to `Form1.cs`?

Comment: And if I put ucModule2.FormInstance.Close(); in UsrCtrlDialog_Click, I get this error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ucModule2.FormInstance'". I will add an answer to my question with my code.

Comment: You didn't create an instance of UserControl. You're using the Type. You can only see static property/fields using the Type. But you have to use an instance of the UC, of course, not its Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're treating the UserControl as a static class object, using it's Type to access Fields and Properties:

```
public partial class ucModule2 : UserControl 
{ 
     public static Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
     // (...)
}
```

Then, in `Form1`:

```
ucModule2.fr2.TopMost = false;
// (...)
```

**`ucModule2`** is the same name of the UserControl Type, so you're trying to use the **Type** to set Fields/Properties that belong to an **Instance** of that Control.

If you added an Instance of `ucModule2` to the Form, then the Designer would have renamed the first Instance of the UC to `ucModule21`.
As usual, adding an index value (`1`, if it's the first instance of that Type) to the name of the Type created.

You need to use the Instance member of that UserControl (or any other control), not its Type.

Some documentation on the subject:

[Inheritance (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/inheritance)
[Members (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/members)

> Classes and structs have members that represent their data and
>   behavior. A class's members include all the members declared in the
>   class, along with all members (except constructors and finalizers)
>   declared in all classes in its inheritance hierarchy...

[Static Classes and Static Class Members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

> To create a non-static class that allows only one instance of itself
>   to be created, see:
>   [Implementing Singleton in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff650316(v=pandp.10)).

It's also quite important to follow a standard naming convention when assigning names to types. Most devs assume that a Type name uses the Pascal Case convention, while an instance of this type will be named using Camel Case convention, as in:

```
MyUserControl myUsrControl = new MyUserControl();
myUsrControl.Show();
```

<sub>You can also see the different Markup colors used for the two, here</sub>

---

**In Form1**:

Call the UserControl's `SetForm()` method from `Form1` (its parent Form).
After that, `Form1` can use the UserControl's `public FormInstance` property.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    // If an Instance of the UC has been added in the Form's Designer,
    // use that instance reference instead 
    UCModule2 ucModule2 = new UCModule2();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucModule2.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        this.Controls.Add(ucModule2);
        ucModule2.SetForm(typeof(Form2));
    }

    private void UsrCtrlDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucModule2?.FormInstance?.Close();
    }
}
```

**In UCModule2** (Type renamed using proper case):

If the Form instance has been closed/disposed by the parent Form, recreate a new instance and reset the public **`FormInstance`** Property.
You can determine whether the Form's instance has been destroyed, testing:

```
FormInstance is null || FormInstance.IsDisposed
```

---

```
public partial class UCModule2: UserControl
{
    public Form FormInstance { get; private set; }

    public Form SetForm(Type formType)
    {
        if (this.FormInstance == null || this.FormInstance.IsDisposed) {
            this.FormInstance = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(formType);
        }
        return this.FormInstance;
    }

    private void simpleButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.FormInstance is null || this.FormInstance.IsDisposed) {
            this.SetForm(FormInstance.GetType());
        }
        this.FormInstance?.Show();
    }
}
```

**Handle a collection of different Form Types generated at run-time**

If more than one form needs to be generated while this UserControl is active, we can add each new instance of a Form Type, determined by the UC's Parent Form, to a List. Then Dispose of each Form instance in the List when the Parent Form *decides* to do it and/or when the UserControl itself is destroyed:

The Parent Form can call the **`SetForm(Type formType)`** public method, setting a Form type to be generated. Then call the **`CloseAllForms()`** public method to close them all when needed.  The UC calls the same method when its handle is being destroyed, to remove existing Form instances (if required).

The Form change the Form Type simply calling `SetForm()` with another type:

```
ucModule2.SetForm(typeof(Form2));
// (... and after...)
ucModule2.SetForm(typeof(Form3));
```

The UC's Button will generate the new Type of Form specified.

**`In Form1`**:

```
public partial class Form1: Form
{
    // If an Instance of the UC has been added in the Form's Designer,
    // use that instance reference instead 
    UCModule2 ucModule2 = new UCModule2();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucModule2.Location = new Point(100, 100);
        this.Controls.Add(ucModule2);
        ucModule2.SetForm(typeof(Form2));
    }

    private void UsrCtrlChangeType_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucModule2.SetForm(typeof(Form3));
    }

    private void UsrCtrlDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucModule2.CloseAllForms();
    }
}
```

**`In UCModule2`**:

```
public partial class UCModule2: UserControl
{
    List<Form> formsCollection = null;

    public UCModule2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        formsCollection = new List<Form>();
    }

    private Type FormType { get; set; }

    // Check whether the new type is different before setting the property,
    // in case the FormType property has an explicit setter.
    public void SetForm(Type formType)
    {
        if (this.FormType != formType) {
            this.FormType = formType;
        }
    }

    public void CloseAllForms()
    {
        if (formsCollection != null && formsCollection.Count > 0) {
            for (int i = formsCollection.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
                formsCollection[i].Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
    {
        CloseAllForms();
        base.OnHandleDestroyed(e);
    }

    private void btnShowForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FormType == null) return;
        var instance = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(FormType);
        formsCollection.Add(instance);
        instance.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer! I have tested it, but no Form opens when I click btnShowForm button.

Comment: `btnShowForm_Click` is of course your `simpleButton1_Click` handler. I forgot to rename it, since that's the name of the Button I used for testing. Just change the name.

Comment: I figured it out. I have seen that it opens as many Form3 windows as I click on simpleButton1. But it happens after I click UsrCtrlChangeType button. Now I want to figure it out how could I open, from ucModule2, from different buttons, Form2 and Form3.